# Syncing Kafka with aws s3 with different directory structure

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have events coming to Kafka and using kafka connect we are syncing these events with aws s3.
Data is visible in s3 in below dir structure:

```
bucket_name/sub_folder/
                       Partition=0/events.json
                       Partition=1/events.json
                       Partition=2/events.json
```

is there a way to store in below dir structure:

```
Bucket_name/sub_folder/date=today_date/ events.json or Partition=0..2/date=today/events.json
Bucket_name/sub_folder/date=today_date/ events.json or
```

Motivation is to store that days events in that that days directory, i searched web but could not find any other way .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`TimeBasedPartitioner`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/configuration_options.html#partitioner) which

> partitions data according to ingestion time.

e.g. for hourly partioning:

```
[…]
"partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
"path.format": "'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH",
"locale": "US",
"timezone": "UTC",
"partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
"timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
"timestamp.field": "my_record_field_with_timestamp_in",
[…]
```

Comment: what will be the behavior in case "RecordField" mentioned contains incorrect value?

Comment: Will there by exceptions thrown in kafka-connect consumer side , if yes what that will be so that we can put them in dead letter queue for later processing. 
i tried with null value it did not synced with s3 but i am not seeing any exception as well.

Comment: In test environment i tried sending one event with null value to RecordField and after that it is not getting started .@Robin

Comment: @Raghav Then don't send bad values? That's only fixable on the Producer side, not at Connect. As soon as it sees a bad record in the partition, it'll stop reading it until you manually restart the task and the bad message is older than the topic retention period